Can I enter Romania by bus with a Bulgaria issued single entry Schengen tourist visa?
I am a Philippine passport holder and have been in Romania last year. My plan is to go to Romania direct at the same day of my arrival in Sofia. I will going to Bucharest by bus.
The question is, will I face issue in the land border if I will do that with my single-entry Schengen visa? I will be staying in Bucharest only for 2 days and back to Sofia and spend the rest of my vacation there. I just need to meet an important friend during weekends.

What itinerary did you present in the visa application?

Itinerary is i will be entering bulgaria and exiting in romania

I understand that -- the question was intended to establish whether you said as much in the visa application and how many days your application indicated you would be spending in each country.  If your currently planned itinerary is the same as the itinerary you submitted with the application then there is very little to worry about indeed.

Yes, you can use a single entry Schengen visa issued by Bulgaria to enter Bulgaria and Romania during the same visit since they are now both in the Schengen area.
Note: If the “Valid for” field on your visa states “-RO”, it would not be valid for Romania.

I mean bulgarian issued schengen can be use in the land border to go to romania right? The thing is i will be traveling to romania the same day of my arrival in sofia bulgaria. Would that be an issue?

Yes, a Schengen visa issued by any country can be used to visit all the others. There should be no issue as long as the majority of your trip will be spent in the issuing country: Bulgaria. See: https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy_en

@JohnDoe Where on the cited page do you find support for your statement that the majority of the trip must or should be spent in the issuing country?

Yeah i’ll have my hotel and ticket to fly back to abu dhabi from bulagaria. It’s just that changing destination on my ticket is like i bought a new ticket

What if my entry and exit is romania? Will i be questioned in romania immig.? Because from there we can have a drive to sofia and stay there and back to bucharest to drop my friend. This case a totally is a new ticket.

https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/Bulgaria/UAE/english/pdf/document-checklist-c-type.pdf In this link is shows that Schengen visa issued from bulgaria can only be utilized via air and sea route. Access to land pr river borders is not allowed. And also for travel itinerary they mentioned “ Entry &  Exit from bulgaria must be air or sea route only”. This is totally confusing.

@DavidRecallsMonica The citation is for the territorial validity of a Schengen visa. Spending the majority of the trip in the country that issued the visa is well known and established in other questions. The only exception is if the main purpose of the visit is briefer than stays elsewhere which doesn’t appear to be the case here. For example, https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/118681/main-destination-of-schengen-visa

@JeselSantos that seems to have been written by someone who misunderstood the meaning of Bulgaria joining the Schengen area for "air and sea only."  That applies to the removal of internal border controls, not to visa validity.  Note that the document is a VFS document, not from a government source.

Thank you guys for the answer. For my peace of mind i sent a mail bulgarian consulate here in uae and they gave an answer already.
